# How to set KUBECONFIG from terraform cloud generate file in github actions

Tags: terraform, github-actions, kubectl, linode

I am trying to set up github actions to run a CI with terraform and kubernetes. I am connecting to terraform cloud to run the terraform commands and it appears to be generating the kubeconfig during the apply process. I get this in the outout:

`local_file.kubeconfig: Creation complete after 0s`

In the next step, I try to run `kubectl` to see the resources that were built, but the command fails because it can't find the the configuration file. Specifically:

`error: Missing or incomplete configuration info.`

So my question is, how do I use the newly generated `local_file.kubeconfig` in my `kubectl` commands?

My first attempt was to expose the `KUBECONFIG` as an environment variable in the github action step, but I didn't know how I would get the value from terraform cloud into the github actions. So instead, I tried to set the variable in my terraform file with a provisioner definition. But this doesn't seem to work.

Is there an easier way to load that value?

Github Actions Steps

```
steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: 'privatebeta-kubes'
      - name: Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
        with:
          cli_config_credentials_token: ${{ secrets.TERRAFORM_API_TOKEN }}
      - name: Terraform Init
        run: terraform init
      
      - name: Terraform Format Check
        run: terraform fmt -check -v
        
      - name: Terraform Plan
        run: terraform plan
        env:
          LINODE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.LINODE_TOKEN }}

      - name: Terraform Apply
        run: terraform apply -auto-approve
        env:
          LINODE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.LINODE_TOKEN }}
      # this step fails because kubectl can't find the token
      - name: List kube nodes
        run: kubectl get nodes
```

and my main.tf file has this definition:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
    kubeconfig = "${local_file.kubeconfig.content}"
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to determine the filesystem location of the result of `local_file.kubeconfig` to set as an environment variable for your `KUBECONFIG`?

Comment: I'm not sure? Ha. I can see that `local_file.kubeconfig` has been created in terraform cloud, but I can't seem to access it from github actions. Is it possible to expose or access from that next step?

Comment: You can see from the exported resource attributes in the doc that you can access the file content or path: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file#argument-reference. One of those should be able to move you forward.